# Vtuberの動きを記録して再生したい

Tags: c#, unity3d

Vtuberの動きを記録して再生したいのですがなにか参考になるものはあるのでしょうか？
下記を参考にキャラクターにFinalIKを充てて頭、手、胴体のpositionとrotateを記録して再生してみたのですが動きませんでした。
https://gametukurikata.com/program/ghost

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/214476

Comment: @fing さん、上手く動かなかったのは設定ミスやバージョン違いなど何かしら原因があることが多いので、もし動かなかった原因を知りたいのであればご自身のなさった方法を箇条書きなどで順番に書いていただくと分かりやすいです。

Comment: 説明としてはVTuberではなく「3Dモデル」とか「3Dキャラクター」の方が適切じゃないかなと思います。

Comment: あるいは、カメラ/センサーデータやモデル/キャラクタの記録ではなく、YouTubeの動画そのものを再生しつつ解析したいとか？